# Can list.iterator() return null?

Tags: java, list, data-structures, iterator, listiterator

Can the iterator method of Interface List ever return null?

I noticed many times people add null checks for list.iterator. Do we really require this check .

Javadocs do not mention iterator to return null ,so wanted to confirm.

link :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#iterator()

Comment: I would never check for null on RETURN from list.iterator(). Of course null-check on the list alone might be reasonable.

Comment: No, we don't require this check. If it isn't stated in the Javadoc, it can't return null. You can't go by what 'many times people [do]'. It isn't a democracy. Redundant code is always wrong.

Comment: Can you provide an example of where somebody uses this check? It really doesn't make much sense that a List would return null for an iterator ever.

Answer (score 10):

`List` is an interface. Whether `List.iterator()` can return `null` depends on the implementation of interface `List` that you are using.

The implementation of standard classes such as `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.LinkedList` never returns `null`, so if you use these it is never necessary to check if `List.iterator()` returns `null`.

You can confirm this by looking at the source code of those classes, which you can find in the file `src.zip` in your JDK installation directory.

In principle it is possible to have a weird implementation of interface `List` that would return `null`, but that would be really strange and not what developers would expect from a `List`.

Comment: you are correct , I voted it up for this, because this point I didn't think before reading your answer, but one thing is clear, If any implementation is returning null, then Its really a weird and strange implementation.  :P

Comment: Whether `List.iterator()` can return null depends on whether it is permitted by the contract specified for the interface, and it isn't.

Comment: @EJP the interface cannot **force** implementations to not return `null`. There's a difference between "can" and "should".

Answer (score 2):

No, list.iterator() can not return null. It will always return a object of the class that is of type Iterable(implementing Iterable interface).

Even in the source code: method `iterator()` is returning new iterable object by using new keyword, so there is no chance of null. Below is the code of ArrayList class's iterator() method:

```
  /**
     * Returns an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence.
     *
     * <p>The returned iterator is <a href="#fail-fast"><i>fail-fast</i></a>.
     *
     * @return an iterator over the elements in this list in proper sequence
     */
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new Itr();
    }
```

Here `Itr is a inner class defined in ArrayList` class itself. 
I have seen some of the List implementations in JDk source code,and I found that everywhere new keyword has been used to return an iterator object, so I think there is no need of null check for list.iterator().

Even when I tried the below code in IntelliJ IDE then I found in IDE info saying that : "`Condition 'iterator != null' is always 'true'`"

```
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
      Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
      if(iterator != null) {
         System.out.println("");
      }
```

Comment: correct, and for example for emptylist it will be EmptyIterator
    
        private static class EmptyList<E>
        extends AbstractList<E>
        implements RandomAccess, Serializable {
        ..
        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return emptyIterator();
        }
  
  public static <T> Iterator<T> emptyIterator() {
        return (Iterator<T>) EmptyIterator.EMPTY_ITERATOR;}

Comment: Of course this method can return `null`. I can very much implement my own List and just implement the method to do so. The question whether this makes sense is another one...

However, it is correct that the standard implementations shipped with the JDK never return null here.

Comment: @Ray, I agree with you, but I saw in Java's built-in List implementations and found that everywhere an iterator object is returned, but If you are creating an implementation of List and then returning null in iterator() method, then in my opinion its not good design, your method must fulfill whatever it is saying.

Comment: @Ray Of course you can do it, but you would be violating the specification of the method.